# FTP shortcuts to another folder

Tags: linux, ftp, putty, sftp

How can I create shortcut from one ftp folder to another using SFTP client such as WinSCP with Putty?

For example, application path is */home/primary/webapps/appication/*

We have created new user with default home directory */home/secondary/*

Using Bash command:

```
 setfacl -R -m u:secondary:rwx /home/primary/webapps/appication/
```

we added full Read-Write permission for secondary user.

To access application folder he suppose to type full path to application folder which is not so convenient for daily usage.

As a solution I would like to create some shortcuts in home directory to this folders as I seen something similar in default cPanel configuration where PUBLIC_HTML folder has some alias such as WWW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a link to the other folder

```
ln -s /home/primary/webapps/application /home/secondary/application
```

This will create a link under `/home/secondary` called "application" which points to `/home/primary/webapps/application`. Once logged in to his home folder, he simply has to click on the "application" folder and will be directed to the proper location.

Comment: I'm receiving permission denied message

Comment: Who's account are you doing it under? What folder are you running the command from? You should be running the command from `/home/secondary/` as the new user. Ensure your permissions are correct. Personally I wouldn't dive into ACLs for something this simple, group permissions and a simple `chown` would suffice.

Comment: I had to add shell access to user for this operation and delete it after. Can you give me more information about ACL because I'm quite new to bash scripting.

Comment: I would not recommend ACLs for something like this.. but if you want to learn more: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/setfacl1.html